# How do I trace a Computed style via Firebug (Firefox)?

Tags: css, firebug, firebug1.5

I see the Computed style (e.g. Width) in Firebug for elements, but how do I find out what exactly caused them?

The main Style tab is useless. There's a change coming in from somewhere that the Style tab doesn't capture. I need to exactly trace what led to the current layout, is Firebug the wrong tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Computed* side panel allows you to expand the computed styles to see the style trace.

[image: *Computed* side panel in Firebug]

Though note that [Firebug 2.0.16 has a bug in combination with Firefox 46.0](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/8018) that is breaking that feature, i.e. you'll see all properties under the *Other* section and they are not expandable and are not filtered. This bug is [already fixed](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/8018#issuecomment-219148644), though there is no new release yet.

Comment: What if my "width" doesn't have an Expand + next to it, it's just a static row?

Comment: Then you either ran into the aforementioned bug or the width is not set by your CSS rules and you have the option *Show User Agent CSS* enabled.